# Unable to use Framework 4.0 in VS2015 c# winforms project

Tags: .net-4.0, visual-studio-2015

I just tried to open an old project that was using Target Dot Net Framework 4.0
My client needs the project use this framework as they are running Windows XP.
When I go to project properties Dot Net Framework 3.5 is available and .Net Framework 4.5 is available but not 4.0
[image]

When I select "Install other frameworks .. " from the list I am taken to the  [this link](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html)  which mentions that framework 4 is included in Visual Studio 2015

When I download the dotNetFx40_Full_x86-x64.exe file for Framework 4 and try to run it I get a message that the installation will not occur because "
Same or higher version of .NET Framework 4 has already been installed on this computer."  and a message to see the read me.

The read me does not mention the error but does point me to [the troubleshooting guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varungupta/archive/2010/06/22/troubleshooting-net-framework-4-install-failures.aspx)  However I do not see the error message here either.

I see that this is a known problem [with earlier versions of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942123/targeting-net-framework-4-when-framework-4-5-is-installed?rq=1)
I see that 4.5 is an "in place replacement" for 4.0  However this does not explain why I cant see both options in my target frameworks combo.

I note in [Scott Hanselman's blog here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx)  that both are available.

I see that frameworks under 4.5.2 are pretty much out of support.
[from the life cycle policy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/framework_faq/en-us)

Comment: i just uninstalled all dotnet frameworks and re-installed 4.0.  Now when I try to open VS2015 Update1 it asks to install v4.5

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all the dot net frameworks from my computer, then uninstalled and reinstalled VS2015 Update1. I can now select .Net Framework 4

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem when installed **VS2017** after **VS2015**: Framework 4.0 just disappeared from project target list.

Following some comments around here  I've tried with NuGet package: *Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform* 1.0.4 and bin fix for 1.0.1.

**Don't** do that! My build time went ~300% up for the same project. It was disaster.

> I see that 4.5 is an "in place replacement" for 4.0 However this does not explain why I cant see both options in my target frameworks combo.

I was reading the same mantra all around the web. It's simply not answer to the problem. Framework 4.0 is **a must** for any industrial machinery related software - because it runs on Windows XP, while .NET 4.5. is useless in my scenario, and probably for many other real-life stuff.

The solution is simple:
You just have to download and **install Visual Studio 2013 Express** from official web page:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44914

After installing it, just open your **VS2015** and you'll see **4.0** again.

[image]

...
"In place replacement ..." argh....